# Is there an algorithm for any given Boolean formula can return the most simplified form of the formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, boolean

Is there an algorithm for any given Boolean formula can return the most simplified form, that is to say, the shortest form with respect to the number of symbols (regarding $\{\lnot, \lor\}$, or $\{\lnot, \lor, \land\}$, for example) of the formula?
Or if not,is there any relevant work?

Comment: "Most simplified" is rather vague. On one definition of it,  there is [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), but it involves solving an NP-complete problem (set cover), in general. See also [Buchfuhrer-Umans, The complexity of Boolean formula minimization](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000010000954).

Answer (score 1):

This work on [minimizing boolean functions](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/courses/Minimize/#:%7E:text=A%20minimal%20form%20of%20a,that%20form%20is%20the%20minimum.) might be what you're looking for. It is quite extensive.